# Weird behavior with document data in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

Disclaimer: I'm very new to Elastic, so if I'm withholding vital data, it's not on purpose.

I'm experiencing some odd behavior with the data I'm sending to be indexed. I have two similar indices, one for dev and one for test. When I send data to dev, everything works fine, data is matching the one I'm sending 100%. When I'm sending data to test, however, for some odd reason some of the data's text case is changing.

For example, if I send `{ "someField": { "InnerField": "Value" } }`, when I look at the indexed document, I'm seeing `{ "someField": { "innerField": "Value" } }` (the `InnerField` key changed case to camel-case).

I compared the index mappings for both indices, they're identical. There's no code that manipulates the data in this way before sending (none that I found, anyway - the data at the moment of being sent is unaltered).

I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something buried deep in the code that was transforming the data, namely the default strategy for the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`